# all variations with nested loop from dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, nested-loops

I have a nested loop, which will assemble all variations of params. the more params, the bigger the nesting will become.

```
for param1 in [1,2,3]:
    for param2 in [5,10,15]:
        for param3 in [10,11,12]:
            for param4 in [35,36,37]:
                for param5 in [2,4,6]:
                    params  = {
                        'param1': param1,
                        'param2': param2,
                        'param3': param3,
                        'param4': param4,
                        'param5': param5,
                    }
                    run_test(params)
```

To make the code a bit more readable, want to put all variations into a dict, and then create the loop above. but how to achieve this?

```
configuration  = {
    'param1': [1,2,3],
    'param2': [5,10,15],
    'param3': [10,11,12],
    'param4': [35,36,37],
    'param5': [2,4,6],
}
```

Desired output is a list of dicts

```
[
    {
        'param1': param1,
        'param2': param2,
        'param3': param3,
        'param4': param4,
        'param5': param5,
    },
    { next dict …}
]
```

The [Cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists) would to work if the input is a `list of lists`, but i have an input which is a `dict of lists`
Suggestions on how to improove the first solution this are highly welcome

Comment: I was going to suggest the same answer that you linked to. Which part of that can't you get to work?

Comment: `list(product(*configuration.values()))`

Comment: Hello! Please do not self-delete and re-post your question when your [previous question is closed](/questions/67905515/nested-loop-from-dict). If you feel that the suggested duplicate doesn't answer your question, you should explain why in an [edit]. After editing, your post will be automatically queued for re-opening.

Comment: i added the desired output, which uses the keys of configuration

Comment: @Brian sorry i did this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use still use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), just [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) back the keys and values

```py
import itertools 

configuration  = {
    'param1': [1,2,3],
    'param2': [5,10,15],
    'param3': [10,11,12],
    'param4': [35,36,37],
    'param5': [2,4,6],
}

for i in itertools.product(*configuration.values()):
    params = dict(zip(configuration.keys(), i))
    run_test(params)
```